# Where to get the Context for DB query?

Tags: go

I am using https://entgo.io/ as entity framework and https://echo.labstack.com/ as web framework.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
func main() {

    client, err := Open("postgresql://pgadmin:pgpw@127.0.0.1/nfeed")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return
    }
    ctx := context.Background()

    if err := client.Schema.Create(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }


    e := echo.New()


    e.GET("/hashtags", func(c echo.Context) error {
        pattern := c.QueryParam("pattern")
        if len(pattern) == 0 {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, err)
        }

        hs, err := client.Hashtag.Query().All(????)


        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Hello")
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":3000"))
}
```

The function call `client.Hashtag.Query().All(context)` expects https://pkg.go.dev/context as parameter.

The question is, how or where can I get the context?
In my opinion, the Echo framework should provide me a Context. Unfortunately, I could not found within the Echo module.

Comment: You can access the request-scoped context by getting the request from the [`echo.Context`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/labstack/echo/v4#Context.Request) and then invoking the [`Context`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17#Request.Context) method on that request, i.e. `c.Request().Context()`. If you don't want the request-specific context, then you should create your own one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a context variable on the line `ctx := context.Background()`, which is a valid `context` type, there's good documentation on this in your own link https://pkg.go.dev/context.

There's no reason that wouldn't work, if you need more then you can check the documentation on how to make a more in depth context variable.

Comment: Don't do this. Use `c.Request().Context()`. The context is canceled when the client's connection closes or the request is canceled.